# Frame for UINavigationItem Title View

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I would like to replicate the way iOS message's title bar title view behaves in an app. (Specifically where it dynamically sizes it's content between the back button and the info button).

My approach has been to create a custom view in a nib that will hold my visual element data, and to put those views inside a stack view, then to make that stack view my navigation item's custom title view.

Using the subview init on the stack view produces a result that just overlays each of it's child views on top of each other. Using a frame initializer gives it a static frame.

I thought to try to and acquire the frame of the bar button items but would like a more seamless, auto layout style way of implementation if one is available.

I'd like it to be able to be the max width between each bar button items.

This is what I'm working with now (called from `viewDidAppear`):

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 58)
    let aView = ConversationPartyView(frame: frame)
    aView.avatar.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    aView.name.text = "Kirk"
    let bView = ConversationPartyView(frame: frame)
    bView.avatar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    bView.name.text = "Spock"
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [aView, bView])
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = stack
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a `UIStackView` you no longer have control of your view's frames. Instead your View classes should override `intrinsicContentSize` too prove the appropriate size for their content and UIStackView will handle the rest.

You can also adjust `UIStackView` `distribution` and `spacing` as needed.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but the stack view seems to behave correctly when I give it's frame property a value, I think my issue is needing to get a dynamic frame for the stack view itself. At least to be wide enough to take up the space between the bar button items.

Comment: Ah I think see more what you're asking. You have your StackView not replacing the navigation bar but as the titleView. And you want it to horizontally adjust its frame based on the bar buttons and rotation?

Comment: That's it exactly.